# Import data into Python from txt file

Tags: python, list, import, python-import, genfromtxt

I have a .txt file with data arranged as follows:

```
3430 4735 1
3430 4736 1
3430 4941 2
3430 5072 1
3430 5095 1
3430 5230 1
3430 5299 1
3430 5386 1
3430 5552 1
3430 5555 1
3430 5808 1
3430 5853 1
3430 5896 1
3430 5988 1
3430 6190 4
3430 6191 1
3430 6225 1
3430 6296 1
```

How can I create Python lists from this, one containing the numbers from the first column, and the other containing the numbers from the second column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look on pandas library, it's very useful for data flow.
http://pandas.pydata.org/

Or you can do this directly :

```
list1 = []
list2 = []
list3 = []
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    for x in content:
        row = x.split()
        list1.append(int(row[0]))
        list2.append(int(row[1]))
        list3.append(int(row[2]))
```

Comment: This also gives me the error "IndexError: list index out of range". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: With the example file ?

Comment: Add a length check before accessing & updating the list inside the for loop.

Comment: The resulting lists have strings as elements. How do I make it so that I have integers instead? @JérémyCaré

Comment: In my code i cast all elements to int, so they are integers not string.
Take a look on int() function

Answer (score 0):

```
one_list = []
another_list = []
with open("somefile.txt", "r") as this_file:
    for line in this_file:
        one_list.append(line.split(' ')[0])
        another_list.append(line.split(' ')[1])
```

Puts the first elements from each line in the file into one list and all the second elements into another list.

Comment: Thanks. When I try to run it, I get the following error: "IndexError: list index out of range"

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
flst = []
slst = []
tlst = []

file = open('your.txt', 'r')
for line in file:
    a = line.split()
    flst.append(int(a[0]))
    slst.append(int(a[1]))
    tlst.append(int(a[2]))
```

Create three empty lists, open the file and read through every line of the txt-file. Then split the lines and add in every line the first, second and third string to a respective list.

Comment: The list elements turn out to be strings while I would prefer them to be integers. How can I fix that?

Comment: You can turn them into integers. I changed the example code.

Answer (score 0):

list1 = []

```
list2 = []
whith open('a.txt','r') as fh:
  lineList = fh.readlines()
  for line in listList:
    numbers = line.strip().split()
    list1.appned(numbers[0])
    list2.extend(numbers[1:])

print(list1)
print(list2)
```